# Errors in explorer.exe when accessing external USB HDD's and some internal partitions on Win7 x86

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, freeze

The whole question is in the title. Details:

- Main problem with a Western Digital My Passport Essentials III 320 GB.
- Same with 2 (3 GB) partitions on an internal 120 GB Samsung HDD.
- OS: Windows 7 32-bit with Kaspersky IS 2012 and ThrottleStop running in the background.
- No shell modifications. No Boot Screen (if even possible) or anything else.
- Virus scan with KIS 2012 is clean as well as registry scan with Tune-Up utilities.
- HDD's confirmed to be working on other computers and I'd ran chckdsk.exe

Any diagnostics or logs you need, just ask.

*April 19, 2012  :  **Bump***

Answer (score 0):

Try running chkdsk /f on those drives.
Corrupt files can crash explorer, especially if you try to perform any operations onto them.
You wrote that you have run it. But was it with /f flag?

Comment: Yes. And I tried the device on other computers; came clean and intact. The problem is with my copy of windows or so I guess.

Comment: Disable all shell extensions(hidden as well) using shellexview.
And run sfc /scannow with admin privileges from command prompt.
Sometimes, there are problems with explorer.exe itself. sfc will fix it.

also try reducing KIS security level to "recommended". keeping it to High can cause disk access problems as well.

Comment: But I never said it was on high; it's actually on low for most except some specific modules. I'd already run sfc and it came clean so I'll try shellexview first this time.

Comment: ok.
also update your windows.
windows update does help to solve problems a few times..

Check settings for "File Antivirus" component of KIS. That module scans files as you access a particular folder.